# Payment succeeds, and our data matches querystring data, but falls thru to INVALID anyway!

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, razor, paypal

Why does my ipn script I wrote always fail? It always goes to INVALID even though it matches everything in the query string that paypal sends to me?

> notification.cshtml?tx=b78v54b5b55rby92S&st=Completed&amt=3.04&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=&merchant_return_link=Return+to+web+site+name&form_charset=UTF-8

And the part that checks it is:

```
string LiveURL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LiveURL);

// Set request back values.
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] parameters = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
string RequestString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(parameters);

RequestString += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
request.ContentLength = RequestString.Length;

// Send request to PP and get response.
StreamWriter Sout = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
Sout.Write(RequestString);
Sout.Close();

StreamReader Sin = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string response = Sin.ReadToEnd();

Sin.Close();
if(result != null && result.OrderStatus == "Confirmed")
{
    switch(response)
    {
        case "VERIFIED":
            if(Request["st"] == "Completed")
            {
                var PPQuery = "SELECT TransactionId, OrderTotal FROM Orders WHERE OrderId = '" + Session["OSFOID"] + "' AND UserId = '" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + "'";
                var ppQueryResult = database.Query(PPQuery);
                foreach(var item in ppQueryResult)
                {
                    decimal fff = 3.04M;
                    if(item["TransactionId"] != Request["tx"])
                    {
                        if(item["OrderTotal"] == TotalPrice)
                        {
                            // Payment was a success. Convey that to the user.
                            output = "Thanks. Order complete.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Possible fraud. Log it.
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This is a duplicate transaction. Log it and Redirect to homepage.
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case "INVALID":
            output = "Invalid was returned. Investigate further.";
            break;
        default:
            output = "Other exception has occured. Investigate further and log.";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the "VERIFIED" block, check:

```
if (Request.Params["payment_status"] == "Completed")
{
        ...

}
```

Request["st"] is incorrect.

Be sure to set IPN URL in one place in PayPal admin and do not use the other form of return URL checking (can't remember the name of it offhand) and IPN at the same time.

There is no "merchant_return_link" parameter; I think it should be "notify_url"... the URL string and the list of params doesn't look right to me; for example: &cm=&item_number

I know your list of params will be unique for your situation, but here's some sample code where I construct the URL to be passed to PayPal:

```
protected string GetPayPalURL(string SERVER_URL, string business, string[] itemNames,
            int[] quantities, decimal[] amounts, double[] weight, string invoiceID, string transID, string NOTIFY_URL)
        {
            // Customer will be required to specify delivery address to PayPal - VERY IMPORTANT
            const string NO_SHIPPING = "2";

            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
            url.Append(SERVER_URL + "?cmd=_cart&upload=1");
            url.Append("&business=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(business));

            for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.Length; i++)
            {
                url.Append("&item_name" + "_" + (i + 1).ToString() + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(itemNames[i]));
                url.Append("&quantity" + "_" + (i + 1).ToString() + "=" + quantities[i].ToString().Replace(",", "."));
                url.Append("&amount" + "_" + (i + 1).ToString() + "=" + amounts[i].ToString().Replace(",", "."));
                url.Append("&weight" + "_" + (i + 1).ToString() + "=" + weight[i].ToString().Replace(",", "."));
            }

            url.Append("&no_shipping=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(NO_SHIPPING));
            url.Append("&custom=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(invoiceID));
            url.Append("&txn_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(transID));
            url.Append("&notify_url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(NOTIFY_URL));

            return url.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: But as you can see "payment_status" never comes thru in the query string. I was originally checking payment_status, but that didn't work. and then I noticed: "st = Completed" and then it started working *more* than it was before

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the params bit - am checking it now. :) Thank you

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show me a sample. I will try it out now - with regards to your `the URL string and the list of params doesn't look right to me`: Yeah, I thught it wasnt right, but thats what paypal sends back to my url, so I thought I had to change to suit what it sends back

Comment: You need to check the PayPal documentation for the correct params for your scenario :-)

Comment: Thank you @irishChieftain - I'm going to mark this as answered, thanks for your help :-) - I did originally check the docs, but I think, obviously I was reading the wrong sections or something.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine. The problem must be with `response` not matching `"VERIFIED"`.

You're not in Turkey by chance, and changing `response` to uppercase prior to the comparison? *

*) If the locale is `Turkey`, uppercasing a string turns `i` into `İ`, not `I` (just one of the many traps with string manipulation)

Comment: Um, nah I'm not in Turkey. I'm in Australia. I'm glad you say the code looks fine because this is my first attempt at paypal stuff. Um, I'll go ahead and try different casing for "VERIFIED" - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Nup, changed "VERIFIED" to "verified" and also "Verified" but still not work.

Comment: Can you print the value of `response` to a log?

Comment: I printed the value of `response` and all it displayed was `INVALID`

Comment: But payments are processed and everything, just not working on my end when i get redirected back to my site

Comment: I have updated my question to show the HttpRequest and stuff that communicates with PayPal

Comment: Can you log the full request/response that is sent to/received from PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Paypal method you are trying to do is as follows on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UsePayPalPaymentInASPNET.aspx)
and if you get payment_status = INVALID, then check the reason in payment_reason

Comment: No, as I said in previous comments, payment was a Success on several occasions - and no, this code is not from a CodeProject article

Comment: You are right! I've checked out that article you linked to now, and checked out responses of other articles and everybody from all these different articles has the exact same problem as me, even though my credit card gets charged (i don't like sandbox) it still always says invalid. How do we fix this?

Comment: @jase in Paypal Sandbox there is Test Accounts menu available on Left when logging to https://developer.paypal.com. There are options like 'Negative 
Test Mode' set it as 'Disabled' or 'N/A' and 'Payment Review' set it as 'Disabled' for the respective seller/buyer account

Answer (score 0):

i dont see in the code where you are defining result which is checked in the if, also in the switch you are checking against request, surely this should be against response?

Comment: Result is defined, and the contents of Result are valid. However, as per articles I've read and tutorials I've followed, they've all said I should be checking against request - but I'll see what happens when I check the other

Comment: wait - are you talking about if(Request["st"] == "Completed")? That checks the QueryString...

Comment: Checking againsnt response doesn't work. Causes compiler dead